# Обновление даты и времени в php Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Есть страница. При заходе на эту страницу, в базу записывается информация о браузере юзера, его ip-адрес, дата и время захода.

Как сделать так, что если один и тот же юзер заходит на страницу под тем же ip-адресом, то обновлялось только время захода, но при этом не создавалась новая строка?

Comment: существует такая штука в mysql как upsert

Comment: Этот вопрос затрагивает слишком много тем, что бы однозначно ответить

Answer (score 6, accepted):

По полям, однозначно идентифицирующим пользователя и ip делаете в таблице уникальный индекс, что бы в таблицу было невозможно вставить две записи касающиеся одной связки пользователь-ip. После этого вставку новой записи в таблицу пишете следующим образом:

```
insert into tableX(ip,user_id,a,b,c,date) values('10.0.0.1',100,'x','y','z',now())
    on duplicate key update date=now();
```

Данный запрос либо вставит новую запись с теми данными что в values, либо, если такая запись существует, выполнит update того, что указано в [`on duplicate key`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Уникальный индекс на таблице создается примерно так:

```
create unique index index_name on table_name(ip, user_id);
```

Так как вам нужна еще и информация о браузере, а пользователь с одного компьютера может воспользоваться разными браузерами (и кстати, иногда один и тот же браузер отдает немного разные идентификационные строки), то в таблице надо будет обеспечивать уникальность по полям ip, user_id, браузер и возможно еще каким то. Если это сложно, т.к. приложение руководствуется сложной логикой определения "той" записи, можно попытаться выполнить update даты, если было изменено 0 строк (см. функцию на подобии [mysql_affected_rows](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-affected-rows.php)) - то выполнить insert.

Comment: а что если несколько пользователей с одного ip?.. Например, несколько человек с одного офиса лазают по сайту... Может создавать cookie и от нее плясать насчет уникального индекса?

Comment: @cyadvert Не заметил про пользователя в вопросе, поправил формулировку.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы.
сейчас у меня вот так выглядит вставка в базу 

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `test` (`ip_address`, `User_agent` ,`View_date` , `Page_url`) 
            VALUES ('".$ip."','".$agent."','".$date."' , '".$url."' )");

мне в конце просто дописать?

on duplicate key update date=now();

Comment: @ИгорьБолдырев  Не совсем, надо что бы таблица сама не позволила вставить вторую запись. надо сделать индекс вроде `create unique index test_ind on test(ip_address, User_agent, Page_url)` (если я правильно понял, что для каждого Page_url у вас отдельный счетчик.

Comment: уникальный индекс создал присвоил в phpmyadmin.

сейчас ip-адреса не дублируются, только вот не пойму как обновлять время, дату.

может получится как нбудь через условие, типа if (#$ip==$ip) { mysql_query("UPDATE test (View_date) VALUES ('".$date."') }

Простите, что догоняю не сразу)

Comment: @ИгорьБолдырев А у вас дата и время в разных полях ? я думал у вас одно поле типа datetime. И свой запрос написал исходя из этого `update View_date=now()`, функция `now()` в mysql - это текущая дата-время, не зачем его формировать в php, mysql сам все сделает.

Comment: Поле всего одно.

Comment: @ИгорьБолдырев Ну и отлично, вот и делайте `now()`

Comment: Спасибо Огромное тебе Mike! Заработало)

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно сделать запрос перед записью вида:
`SELECT id FROM tableUser WHERE ip = '$ipuser'`
Если данный запрос вернет вам значение `id` делаем запрос Update по этому полю

Comment: Можно конечно, только надо тогда еще и про блокировки не забывать. Ибо, если на сервер практически одновременно придут два запроса с одним ip, то может оказаться, что первый обратится в базу, не найдет запись, приготовится ее вставить, тут его прервет ОС (она же многозадачная), отдаст управление второму процессу, он вставит свою запись, потом управление вернется к первому, который думает что записи нет и он то же попытается ее вставить и получит ошибку, ну либо продублирует запись, если условия уникальности на таблице ее пропустят

Comment: да вы правы, я написал как идею проверки реализация это ваше)

Answer (score 0):

Я бы рекомендовал либо:

- Делать хэш из User-Agent + IP и по нему уже делал INSERT INTO table (hash, ip, lastdate) VALUES(?, ?, now() ) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...
- Надо понимать что под нагрузкой больше 200 реквест в секунду это ляжет, надо сохранять лог в файл потом его аггрегировать в оффлайне