# Объединение UPDATE и INSERT

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin, php7

Добрый день!

Написал два запроса к базе данных.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли упростить следующий код и как, если можно:

```
mysqli_query($soedinenie, "UPDATE `test` SET `data`='$time_insert', `data_col`=`data_col`+1
                           WHERE `id` = '$login'");
mysqli_query($soedinenie, "INSERT INTO `test` (`email`, `data`, `data_col`)
                           VALUES ('$email', '$time_insert', '$logcol')");
```

Насколько я понял, `UPDATE` и `INSERT` объединить нельзя, но я могу ошибаться:)

При 1-ом запросе, запись уже в базе данных содержится, её нужно просто обновить, а при 2-ом запросе, запись вставляется впервые, и больше этот блок запросов к базе данных выполняться не будет, т.к. при новом обращении уже на `php` сработает определенная проверка, и будут выполняться совсем другие запросы.

Comment: А какой эффект вы хотите получить от их объединения ? Есть например `insert ... on duplicate key update ...` который пытается вставить запись, а если она уже существует - то обновить

Comment: @Mike При 1-ом запросе, запись уже в базе данных содержится, её нужно просто обновить, а при 2-ом запросе, запись вставляется впервые, и больше этот блок запросов к базе данных выполняться не будет, далее уже на `php` сработает проверка, и будет выполняться совсем другие запросы.

Comment: Все равно не понял, какова цель их объединения. Их можно выполнять как сейчас, либо упростить до одного запроса `insert ... on duplicate key` который сам разберется вставлять запись или обновлять (правда после его выполнения вы не сможете понять что именно он сделал, вставил или обновил, если это конечно имеет значение для дальнейшей логики программы)

Comment: @Mike Скорее вопрос в оптимизации запросов. Думаю, что 2 запроса все же не красиво. В один думаю быстрее отработает.

Comment: Но ведь один из них не будет отрабатывать. Если предположить, что запись чаще есть, чем ее нет.  Вы можете после update проверить `mysqli_affected_rows()` что бы узнать была ли обновлена запись (т.е. существовала ли она)

Comment: @Mike У меня на `php` проверки работают отлично, как раз с помощью `mysqli_affected_rows()`. Можно упростить или нет? А то разговор смещается  в другую сторону)

Comment: Да, можно, если при логике вашего приложения подходит то, что я предложил в первом комментарии (вставка, а если запись есть - то обновление). Правда вы так и не сказали, не навело ли это предложение на какие то мысли (например: "да, это интересно", "нет, это не укладывается в логику приложения")

Comment: @Mike Ну смотрите, при первом запросе вообще у меня обновляется ip, а при втором запросе вставляется в БД емайл (срабатывает этот блок действий, когда нет емайла такого в БД, поэтому его нужно вставить, а ip обновить), далее, когда снова сработает некий код, сработает проверка - ip и емайл уже есть такой, поэтому вставлять не надо емайл, сработает другой блок действий `elseif` в котором будет уже обновляться снова ip и емайл в одном запросе. Если с помощью Вашего предложенного варианта можно упростить мой код, то с радостью его рассмотрю:)

Comment: Ok, так подойдет https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/499925/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%B2-php-mysql/499932#499932

Comment: @Mike Надеюсь Вы поняли, что в 1-ом запросе обновление одной записи (ip) происходит в базе данных и вставляется новая запись (емайл) новой строкой 2-ым запросом. В Вашем примере, как я понял для одной записи.

Comment: Нет, это по вашему примеру это понять сложно. обновление и вставка идет в одну таблицу, причем при вставке в ту же таблицу, не вставляется поле id, что выглядит странно. Я предполжил что это ошибка и под id и в первом и во втором случае имелся ввиду email. Короче - два разных действия выполнить сразу невозможно...

Comment: Хотя если таблица действительно одна и очень хочется, то можно было бы изобразить что то вроде `insert into test ... select 'login','$time_insert', ... UNION select 'login2','$time_insert' on duplicate key update data=values(...)` и подобрать результаты двух select так что бы первый наткнулся на дубль и заапдейтил запись, а второй вставил бы новую, так как дубля бы не создалось. Но это сложно назвать оптимизацией, только усложняет читабельность кода