# Как сделать select выборку из mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Необходимо проверить наличие id в базе данных и выполнить действие (добавить или обновить).

Не получается корректно создать select запрос т.к. **xfields** поле с несколькими значениями разделенными двойным ||, пример:

price|123456||time|5

price|123000||time|1

price|456||time|2

price|1456||time|1

price|**уникальный id**

```
foreach($items -> channel -> item as $item) {

$price = $item->price;

$RES = $db->super_query("SELECT * FROM ".PREFIX."_post WHERE xfields='price|$price'",true);

   if( $RES > 0 ) {
       // действие 1

   } else {
       // действие 2

   }

}
```

Как правильно выполнять select и обрабатывать результат (запись есть, записи нет)?

Спасибо!

Comment: `concat('|', xfields, '|') like concat('%|price|', ?, '|%')` Вопросительный знак - ваши данные, я предполагаю что в запрос они передаются все таки не прямой подстановкой переменной, что не безопасно, а через подготовленные запросы (https://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepare.php) Тем более, что prepare можно выполнить один раз перед циклом, а execute уже делать в цикле, что несколько быстрее. Хотя это будет и не заметно, сам запрос к сожалению будет очень медленным, ибо полный перебор всей таблицы гарантирован...

Comment: Возможно стоит задуматься об изменении подхода: структуры БД или проверки множества записей за раз

Comment: А еще очень может быть что вы изобретаете велосипед. Что то мне подсказывает, что подобный формат хранения данных продиктован каким то движком. А тогда наличие записи надо проверять какими то функциями самого движка, они просто обязаны существовать

Comment: @Mike, если price сделать отдельным полем таблицы, запрос выполняться будет быстрее?

Comment: Да, особенно если на это поле построить индекс. И если при этом правильно выбрать поля по которым построить уникальный индекс (не допускающий повторов значений), то предварительный поиск можно будет вообще не использовать, а сразу делать `insert ... on duplicate key update ...` который вставляет запись если ее нет и изменяет - если есть. Хотя одно price на роль уникального как то не тянет. У двух товаров могут быть одинаковые цены

Comment: У двух товаров могут быть одинаковые цены, данное значение у меня уникально на 100%. Если я изменю базу данных, как сразу делать `insert ... on duplicate key update ... ` в моем примере, который вставляет запись если ее нет и изменяет - если есть без предварительного поиска?

Comment: для этого как раз price должен быть уникальным ключем (индексом) что бы обычная попытка вставить повтор приводила к ошибке. а потом https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/499932/194569

Comment: Уже имеется id, price тоже можно сделать уникальным? Ранее не сталкивался с этим.

Comment: Т.е. не может быть строк в котором точно такая же пара значений id и price ? Да, можно, уникальный индекс строится на два поля, т.е. `create unique index table_uniq on table(id, price)`

Comment: Да, строки не повторятся. Спасибо, буду базу переделывать.

Comment: @Mike вот я начал делать и остановился на odku https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1146773/Как-обновить-или-записать-данные-в-базу-mysql-через-подготовленные-запросы-и-odk Не могу верно настроить, посмотрите, пожалуйста.