# Как обновить или записать данные в базу mysql через подготовленные запросы и odku?

Tags: php, mysql

Записываю данные в базу следующим образом:

```
<?php
require_once 'connection.php'; // подключаем скрипт

// Создание соединения
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
// Проверка соединения
if ($conn->connect_error) {
   die("Ошибка подключения: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
        $up_date = date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s');

// Подготовить и связать
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO offer (affiliate, date, day_sales, description, image, item_id, price_total, rate, sales, sales_per_day, timer, title, totalPartners, totalReward, up_date, user_fullname, user_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

on duplicate key update affiliate = '116', day_sales = '11000'");

// on duplicate key update VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");


$stmt->bind_param("isissiiiiissiissi", $affiliate, $date, $day_sales, $description, $image, $item_id, $price_total, $rate, $sales, $sales_per_day, $timer, $title, $totalPartners, $totalReward, $up_date, $user_fullname, $user_id);


// Установить параметры и выполнить
$affiliate = "1"; 
$date = "$up_date"; 
$day_sales = "1"; 
$description = "Феодал системс"; 
$image = "Федор"; 
$item_id = "1111"; 
$price_total = "1"; 
$rate = "1"; 
$sales = "1"; 
$sales_per_day = "1"; 
$timer = "$up_date"; 
$title = "Федор"; 
$totalPartners = "1"; 
$totalReward = "1"; 
$up_date = "$up_date"; 
$user_fullname = "Федор"; 
$user_id = "777";
$stmt->execute();
echo "Успешно созданы новые записи";

// Закрыть связь
$stmt->close();
// Закрыть подключение
$conn->close();

?>
```

В базу пишется уникальный id записи (AUTO_INCREMENT) и уникальный item_id.

Мне необходимо в цикле проверять наличие записи в базе по **ее уникальному $item_id** и если она есть, то обновлять ее, если записи нет, то добавлять ее.

Необходимо сразу делать `insert ... on duplicate key update ...` без предварительного поиска который вставляет запись если ее нет и изменяет - если она есть.

Пробовал адаптировать свой код под [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/499925/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%B2-php-mysql/499932#499932) но не получилось корректно настроить **on duplicate key update VALUES**.

`on duplicate key update VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");` не работает.

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: В секции ODKU следует использовать функцию VALUES() для обновления полей, требующих такого обновления.

Comment: Меня устроило бы и это `on duplicate key update affiliate = '116', day_sales = '11000'");` но как в значения подставлять нужные данные $affiliate, $day_sales и т.д. `on duplicate key update affiliate = '$affiliate', day_sales = '$day_sales'");` не работает.

Comment: То есть посмотреть описание указанной функции Вы не удосужились даже... вот нафига тогда вообще спрашивать было, если советы - игнорируются?

Comment: Я описание функции смотрел, но не смог применить ее в данной конструкции. Пробовал по примерам https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html но ничего не получилось.

Comment: `on duplicate key update affiliate = values(affiliate), day_sales = values(day_sales)`

Comment: @Mike, спасибо!